# Fluent NHibernate Components that share columns

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, components

How can you have a component, appear on a entity more than once, and one of the columns in the component are shared?

```
    mapping.Component(x => x.Price1, m =>
    {
        m.Map(x => x.Amount).Column("OfferPrice");
        m.Map(x => x.Group).Column("CurrencyConverterRateGroupID");
    });

    mapping.Component(x => x.Price2, m =>
    {
        m.Map(x => x.Amount).Column("OfferPrice2");
        m.Map(x => x.Group).Column("CurrencyConverterRateGroupID");
    });
```

This errors during insert, just saying like cannot get column 53 of 53 or something. It's a general error when it has mapping problems. Selects work fine, but you cannot insert or update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map to the same columns, but you'd have to make one of them readonly

```
mapping.Component(x => x.Price1, m =>
{
    m.Map(x => x.Amount).Column("OfferPrice");
    m.Map(x => x.Group).Column("CurrencyConverterRateGroupID");
});

mapping.Component(x => x.Price2, m =>
{
    m.Map(x => x.Amount).Column("OfferPrice2");
    m.Map(x => x.Group).Column("CurrencyConverterRateGroupID").Readonly();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't map the same column twice in your mapping.  You would need to pull `CurrencyConverterRateGroupID` out of the component.

Comment: You sure there isn't a way to make custom filters or something to do it?